# Is it possible use dotNetInstaller without .net framework 3.5 installed on computer?

Tags: c#, windows, .net-3.5, .net-4.5, dotnetinstaller

I need to create a bootstrapper using dotNetInstaller 2.2. But my computer does not have .Net framework 3.5 installed and only .net 4.5 is installed. When I am trying to create the bootstrapper Windows is prompting to download and install .net 3.5 on my computer. I already tried this using a configuration file for the InstallerLinker.exe with the follwing configs.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
    <startup> 
        <supportedRuntime version="v4.0"/>
    </startup>
</configuration>
```

So can anyone please tell me whether it is possible to use DotNetInstaller 2.2 without .net framework 3.5 on the computer ?